# JS font-resize not working gradually in browsers apart from IE

Tags: javascript, css, browser, fonts, resize

I am resizing a font in javascript until it floods the div it's in. I do this because the layout of the site is fluid and thus the div's size changes and I want to match the font accordingly.

It's a simple loop:

```
    while (!overflow(div)) {
        fontSize += 1;
        div.css("font-size", fontSize + "%");
    }
```

Curiously, only IE does it correctly.

Chrome, Firefox and Opera don't adjust the font size linearly, but in irregular intervals.

E.g. Chrome will only adjust the font-size at 108%, 120% and 129%, seemingly ignoring all the values in between. 
Moz and Opera have their own intervals (smaller ones at that), so it's not easy to figure out what's going on there.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: I would guess while loop is running faster than the DOM update happens. Just a wild guess.

Comment: What is your overflow function?

Comment: `function overflow(obj) {
 return (obj[0].scrollHeight / obj[0].clientHeight > 1) ? true : false;
}`

Comment: Two years later, and I'm still running into this problem in all other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

WebKit-based browsers and Firefox are optimised to stagger and batch updates to the DOM to make page rendering more efficient overall. The idea is that multiple, contiguous updates to the DOM rarely require an individual render, but just one render at the end. However, there's still a way to trigger a render. Just call a getter that forces the browser to re-layout the page.

```
o = div.offsetWidth;
```

Adding that inside your loop, after setting the style property, would trigger a render with each iteration.

There's [a list](http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/03/how-not-to-trigger-layout-in-webkit.html) of all the methods and getter properties that trigger a re-layout in WebKit on Google engineer Tony Gentilcore's blog.

Comment: No, that didn't do it. No effect. The "gaps" also persist if I wait. Say, I'm resizing my browser window: IE adjusts the fonts nicely along the way, but Chrome jumps between sizes, creating gaps. I can also pause at a jump and then zig zag between (e.g.) 108% and 120% when it really should only be 1 or 2 percent.